# jQuery inside colorbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opencart

I have an issue with colorbox content and can't figure out what to do with it. and also, I'm not very familiar with jQuery.

I have a Colorbox which displays the usual html content (it is not iframe-d). There I have a little script for calculation depended on checkbox selection. This code works fine on a static page, but not working inside Colorbox. I read about $.colorbox.element() but didn't get it..

Here's my part of code, any help is highly appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('[id^=acc]').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $('‪#‎total‬').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
        $('‪#‎monthly‬').text(parseInt($('#monthly').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('monthly')));
    } else {
        $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
        $('#monthly').text(parseInt($('#monthly').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('monthly')));
    } 
}); 
//--></script>

<span id="total">0</span> AZN
<span id="monthly">0</span> AZN
<input type="checkbox" class="accCheck" id="acc1" name="accessory[]" data-amount="100" data-monthly="15"/>
<label for="acc1"><span></span>Add to credit</label>
```

This is the part of code that calling form to be printed inside colorbox

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function() { 
    $("[id^=onlineCredit]").submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $.colorbox({html:data});
        },
        'html');
        return false;
    });
});
//--></script>
```

Comment: Errors (console) ? Something?

Comment: nothing ((( the matter is that this code is fully working on normal page

Comment: i guess this could be an issue with pointing browser that those two spans (#total and #monthly) are actually colorbox elements

Comment: could you show the code whereby you are using this in conjunction with the colorBox?

Comment: why don't you setup a http://jsfiddle.net/ showing the problem?

Comment: i'm afraid i can't set up jsfiddle to show the code inside colorbox

Comment: Secret Squirrel, I updated the question in post

Comment: @FelixAbdullayev So part of the `HTML` you are returning to display in the `colorbox` contains the checkbox script which increments or decrements the amount?

Comment: @SecretSquirrel, as i can see now it's not. I placed the code calculating checkboxes inside php file called by colorbox. Should I somehow combine this script with other data in       $.colorbox({html:data});
?

Comment: @FelixAbdullayev I am not familiar with `colorbox` myself. To me I think this is just an issue with how the `HTML` being returned from the post is being rendered when the colorbox

Answer (score 0):

page1.html

```
<span id="total">0</span> AZN
<span id="monthly">0</span> AZN
<input type="checkbox" class="accCheck" id="acc1" name="accessory[]" data-amount="100" data-monthly="15"/>
<label for="acc1"><span></span>Add to credit</label>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#acc1').click(function() {
            if($(this).attr("checked")) {
                $('#‎total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
                $('#‎monthly').text(parseInt($('#monthly').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('monthly')));
            } else {
                $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
                $('#monthly').text(parseInt($('#monthly').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('monthly')));
            } 
        });
    </script>
```

page2.html

```
<form class="ajax" href="page1.html"> 
     <input  type="submit"/>
</form>

<link href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".ajax").colorbox({width:"50%"});
    });
</script>
```

try this :)

Comment: yes if you want calling form from other page html.
see here http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Comment: colorbox is opened after form submission. i guess that the $.colorbox({html:data}); is not the correct way to call it. I should consider to change the type to inline or iframe... but this will affect all my project ((

Comment: you want open colorbox after form submission ?

Comment: if you want colorbox opened after form submission 
change link in page2.html with 

<form class="ajax" href="page1.html">
    <input  type="submit"/>
</form>

Comment: i've checked those page1 and page2 html files. Came with dala loading error .. still searching for a solution to that

Comment: if the error is "This content failed to load." then check the href in your form this example work with me .
you see my last answer ??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the script to the page you are displaying the `colorbox` on.

also look for the use of `prop` and `attr` as `attr("checked")` was undefined in my browser.

for example

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('[id^=acc]').click(function() {

        alert($(this).attr("checked")); -- this doesn't work on my browser
        alert($(this).prop("checked")); -- this does.

        if($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $('‪#‎total‬').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
            $('‪#‎monthly‬').text(parseInt($('#monthly').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('monthly')));
        } else {
            $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
            $('#monthly').text(parseInt($('#monthly').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('monthly')));
        } 
    });         

       $(function() { 
            $("[id^=onlineCredit]").submit(function() {
                $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                    $.colorbox({html:data});
                },
                'html');
                return false;
             });
    });
<\script>
```

Comment: didn't work (( i guess that the click to checkbox inside colorbox isn't recognized by browser

Comment: After the `colorbox` appears, I would `viewSource` of the page and inspect what has been rendered, this may help you in discovering why it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> other solution with form in same page

```
<a id="inline" href="#myForm">myForm</a>
<form id="myForm" style="display:none">
    <span id="total">0</span> AZN
    <span id="monthly">0</span> AZN
    <input type="checkbox" class="accCheck" id="acc1" name="accessory[]" data-amount="100" data-monthly="15"/>
    <label for="acc1"><span></span>Add to credit</label>
    <input  type="submit"/>
</form>
<link href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#inline").click(function(){
            $("#myForm").css("display","inline");
        }).colorbox({inline:true, href:"#myForm",width:"50%",
                        onClosed:function(){
                                    $("#myForm").css("display","none");
                                }
                    });
    });
    $('#acc1').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $('#‎total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
            $('#‎monthly').text(parseInt($('#monthly').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('monthly')));
        } else {
            $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
            $('#monthly').text(parseInt($('#monthly').text()) - parseInt($(this).data('monthly')));
        } 
    });
</script>
```